# when moving css file to different folder i am losing UL background image?

Tags: css

sorry i am new to CSS. I am doing a school unit where i have to create a web page using CSS based on an image design. Anyway, i finally finished and everything works great. though i found out that as a requirement for my unit i need to have my CSS file in a folder called 'styles'. so i created a new folder called 'styles', i placed my site.CSS file in there then updated my css link from:

```
 <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

to

`<link href="styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` to cater for the new file path.

When i open the webpage every thing remains the same except for my unordered list background image does not display? everything else that is styled in the CSS file all works fine, just only the background image for my UL disappears. But when i put the CSS file back where it was originally from(same path as my Index.html file) and change the path back to  it all works fine again and the background image re-appears.

What could i be doing wrong? i just can't figure out what to do.

the css code for the particular style:

```
#menu a {
 height: 30px; 
 display: block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-size: small;
 padding-top: 8px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-image: url('images/pg_menu_bg.png');
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help, i hope this isn't a stupid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've changed the directory structure of your project.

When you reference a filepath in css without a slash at the start, the browser assumes you are referencing relative to where the CSS file is, so when you place the CSS file in the `styles` directory, it's looking for the image in:

/styles/images/pg_menu_bg.png

Where the image actually exists in:

/images/pg_menu_bg.png

This is why it works when you put the css file back in the root directory (I hope that makes sense?)

You should be able to get around this by changing your background css to:

`background-image: url('../images/pg_menu_bg.png');`

the `../` essentially means go up one directory from the directory the css file is located in.

It would be even better to write is as:

`background-image: url('/images/pg_menu_bg.png');`

The slash at the beginning tells the browser to look in the root directory, this means that regardless of where your css file is located the code should work. Unfortunately this doesn't work if you're accessing the html files on your computer (as the root of your computer is C:/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the path of your background image also. Now your CSS file isn't in the root location anymore. So you have to use something like this - 

`background-image: url('../images/pg_menu_bg.png');`